# AppRecordingManager.GetDefault() in UWP app error

Tags: vb.net, uwp, windows-10-universal

I've written a UWP app that will only run on desktop.

I need to take a screenshot of the app and am trying to use appRecordingmanager for this.

However I keep getting an exception on GetDefault() method

[image]

here is my code:

```
    Dim manager As AppRecordingManager = AppRecordingManager.GetDefault()
    Dim status = manager.GetStatus()

    If status.CanRecord OrElse status.CanRecordTimeSpan Then
        Dim result = Await manager.SaveScreenshotToFilesAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "screnshot", AppRecordingSaveScreenshotOption.HdrContentVisible, manager.SupportedScreenshotMediaEncodingSubtypes)
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Succeeded)

        If result.Succeeded Then

            For Each item In result.SavedScreenshotInfos
                Debug.WriteLine(item.File.DisplayName)
            Next
        Else
            Debug.WriteLine(result.ExtendedError.Message)
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: The APIs are not available on devices running an OS version earlier than Windows 10, version 1709. So please make sure the app's min version large than 16299

Comment: Hi Thanks, changed the min version to 17134 but still have the same issue. looking at the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.apprecording.apprecordingmanager?view=winrt-19041 it states that the follwoing versions are supported: Build 19041 Build 18362 Build 17763 Build 17134 Build 16299

Comment: my laptop is currently on 17134 so I can't go any higher. updating now to the latest version. Will test again once done, hopefully it resolves the issue.

Comment: its working now after the update, target version is set to to 18362 and min version set to 17134. Thanks for the help Nico

Answer (score 0):

Updated my laptop OS to the latest version, set target version to 18362 and min version to 17134. all working now.